# Setting Input Value Programmatically Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to submit [this form](https://member.ubutler.nl/) programmatically, but nothing happens when I set the value of the input programmatically. It works when I enter the value manually in the browser and then call `button.click()`.

I'd say this should work:

```
document.getElementById("search").value = "31600000000"
document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/button", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()
```

Based on other SO answers I tried all kinds of things, in various combinations. Here's a complete example of all that I tried:

```
document.getElementById("search").focus()
document.getElementById("search").value = "31600000000"
document.getElementById("search").setAttribute('value', "31600000000")
document.getElementById("search").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keypress", {
  view: window,
  keyCode: 13,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
}))
document.getElementById("search").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))
document.getElementById("search").onchange()
document.getElementById("search").dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
document.getElementById("search").oninput()
document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/button", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.disabled = false
document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/button", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.click()
```

Other things I tried:

- Tried in different browsers (Chrome, Firefox & Safari)
- Get the input by xpath to rule out id conflicts
- Submitting the form instead of clicking the button, but then the entire page reloads for some reason (`document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.submit()`

Observations:

- The changed value is reflected on the page when I set the value using the browser console
- When I click the input however, the value changes back to it's original (also when getting the value in the console)
- It works when I manually enter a valid number and invoke the submit button via the console
- The submit button stays disabled when setting a valid value via the console, but is properly enabled when setting the value manually.

I'm guessing it has something to do with events or validation, but I'm not well-versed in Javascript or HTML and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Why don't you trigger the form submit event instead of triggering the button click event?

Comment: I tried that too, actually, but then the entire page reloads. I'll edit my question to add this.

Comment: Can you assign an id to the button and then use: `document.getElementById("submitButton").click()` ? Or is there a reason you're evaluating using the xpath? I feel like the evaluation might be resetting the page since the context is defaulted to "document"

Comment: It's a third party website so I don't control the code, but assuming the right way to do this is `document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.id = "submitButton"`, and then clicking with `document.getElementById("submitButton").click()`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Is your code running within the page document or are you attempting to fill the value and submit externally?

Comment: And if external, are you on that same domain?

Comment: Not sure, how can I tell? I guess so though, since I'm using the Firefox web console within the context of this website.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but hopefully it sets you in the right direction:

Instead of using `button.click()`, try using `form.submit()`

So your submit would look like:

`document.evaluate("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.submit()`

Also, I saw some posts suggesting an alternative way to set `value` that you may want to consider for future testing:
`document.getElementById("search").setAttribute("value", "31612345678")`

Maybe try setting your input value with both methods until you get some progress. Unfortunately I still wasn't able to get any traction with it either - best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Tyler! I tried both but neither works. Since I posted I was able to get it to work with Selenium Webdriver, using `input.sendKeys(value)` and `input.submit()` (which automatically finds the form to submit according to the documentation). But it's still a mystery to me why setting the value property and attribute isn't the same as entering a value in the browser.